# MYSQL Inventory count per date range

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a report that shows how many items are available within a specific date range, entered by the user. It should coordinate with requested variable start and end dates...

Start: **2021-01-10** / End: **2021-01-15** results should be...

```
1234 | table | 050 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-12 | 085
1234 | chair | 200 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-12 | 300
1234 | light | 002 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-12 | 005
5678 | table | 025 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 085
5678 | light | 003 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 005
9876 | table | 010 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-14 | 085
9876 | chair | 100 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-14 | 300
2323 | light | 010 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 010
```

Start: **2021-01-13** / End: **2021-01-18** results should be...

```
5678 | table | 025 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 035
5678 | light | 003 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 013
9876 | table | 010 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-14 | 035
9876 | chair | 100 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-14 | 100
2323 | light | 010 | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-15 | 013
```

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  (SELECT CAST(SUM(t2.quantity) AS CHAR)
   FROM timetable t2 
   WHERE t2.item = t1.item) AS itm_sum
FROM timetable t1

SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  (SELECT CAST(SUM(t2.quantity) AS CHAR)
    FROM timetable t2 
    WHERE t2.item = t1.item) AS itm_sum
FROM timetable t1
 WHERE ('2021-01-13 10:00:00' <= dt_END) AND
```

(dt_start <= '2021-01-18 10:00:00')

I am getting incorrect results.

The beginning Fiddle is here....
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5WtkgisvjN4VvwwKai3BP/3#&togetherjs=JLKJ4PjgsU

Comment: Can @verace help?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? Getting input from the user?

Comment: Nope, the user inputs the dates. The issue is I am not getting the inventory counts correctly once I add dates into it.

Comment: When I enter the 2021-01-10 through 2021-01-12, I get the result I want. When I enter 2021-01-13 through 2021-01-18, I get a zero result set

Comment: What are you using for your filtering criteria?

Comment: I just updated the Fiddle...
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5WtkgisvjN4VvwwKai3BP/3#&togetherjs=JLKJ4PjgsU

When I run the dates from 13th - 18th, I get 300 chairs instead of 100 and my other numbers are off too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simole your inner SELECT counts every row that it gets, from timetable so you have to rstrict also the inner SEELCT

> ```
> CREATE TABLE timetable (
> id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
> project_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
> item VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
> quantity INT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
> dt_start DATETIME,
> dt_END DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO timetable (project_id,item,quantity,dt_start,dt_end)
> VALUES
> (1234, 'table', 50, '2021-01-10 10:00:00', '2021-01-12 10:00:00'),
> (1234, 'chair', 200, '2021-01-10 10:00:00', '2021-01-12 10:00:00'),
> (1234, 'light', 2, '2021-01-10 10:00:00', '2021-01-12 10:00:00'),
> (5678, 'table', 25, '2021-01-12 10:00:00', '2021-01-15 10:00:00'),
> (5678, 'light', 3, '2021-01-12 10:00:00', '2021-01-15 10:00:00'),
> (9876, 'table', 10, '2021-01-10 10:00:00', '2021-01-14 10:00:00'),
> (9876, 'chair', 100, '2021-01-10 10:00:00', '2021-01-14 10:00:00'),
> (2323, 'light', 10, '2021-01-12 10:00:00', '2021-01-15 10:00:00');
>
> CREATE TABLE calendar (dt date not null primary key);
> INSERT INTO calendar (dt)
> VALUES ('2021-01-9'),('2021-01-10'),('2021-01-11'),('2021-01-12'),
> ('2021-01-13'),('2021-01-14'),('2021-01-15'),('2021-01-16'),
> ('2021-01-17'),('2021-01-18'),('2021-01-19'),('2021-01-20');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   t1.*, 
>   (SELECT CAST(SUM(t2.quantity) AS CHAR)
>    FROM timetable t2 
>    WHERE t2.item = t1.item
>    AND    ('2021-01-13 10:00:00' <= date(dt_END))
>   AND
>   (date(dt_start) <= '2021-01-18 10:00:00')
> ) AS itm_sum
> FROM timetable t1
>     WHERE
>   ('2021-01-13 10:00:00' <= date(dt_END))
>   AND
>   (date(dt_start) <= '2021-01-18 10:00:00')
> ```
>
> ```
> id | project_id | item  | quantity | dt_start            | dt_END              | itm_sum
> -: | ---------: | :---- | -------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------
>  4 |       5678 | table |      025 | 2021-01-12 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 35     
>  5 |       5678 | light |      003 | 2021-01-12 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 13     
>  6 |       9876 | table |      010 | 2021-01-10 10:00:00 | 2021-01-14 10:00:00 | 35     
>  7 |       9876 | chair |      100 | 2021-01-10 10:00:00 | 2021-01-14 10:00:00 | 100    
>  8 |       2323 | light |      010 | 2021-01-12 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c12f2cbba9de3d1c796ddd308446739)*

Comment: Eureka! I think you did it... again. I am sort of think I understand what you did, but it is way above my coding skills. Thank you!!

Comment: it takes time, to learn such things and it helps to see the ansets here and on SO how they solve problems

Comment: Well put. Between the code I got yesterday and what I got today, has been super helpful!! Have a great week.